# Physical interpretation of Wheeler - Dewitt equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity

What  is  the  mainstream ( if  there  is one )  interpretation  of  the  Wheeler - Dewitt  equation  $\hat{H}\Psi =0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It very important in theoretical physics, especially in quantum gravity. The Hamiltonian is a constraint in quantized general relativity. Unlike ordinary quantum field theory or quantum mechanics, the Hamiltonian is a first class constraint on physical states. We also have an independent constraint for each point in space.